# ActiveX checkbox unwanted label font change on a click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few ActiveX checkboxes in my Excel sheet. When I click on them, label font seems to increase every time.

I tried to reset it using below code

```vb
MyLabel.Font.Size = 11
MyLabel.Font.Size = 11
MyLabel.Height = MyLabel.Height + 1
MyLabel.Height = MyLabel.Height - 1
```

It works on my machine. If I use remote desktop to log in from a different (larger screen) machine, above code fails.

If I click on a checkbox, it reduces the size tremendously and doesn't reset until I click on a different cell.

Are there any checks I can put in the code so it behaves consistently.

Comment: ActiveX buttons can be buggy. I prefer form controls to them. Is that not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to use ActiveX

Comment: Are you using this on a second monitor setup? I had issues with ActiveX when the workbook was visible in my second monitor, but it worked fine in the primary monitor.

Comment: Good point. I just checked that as well and I tried as the primary monitor but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this comes from changing screens/and/or screen resolution with Excel open.  Usually happened when I undocked my laptop with Excel open and then tried to continue working.  I seem to be able to fix it by closing Excel (don't save if the font is wonky) and then reopen excel and your workbook in the environment (display, machine, etc.) where you want to continue working.

Whenever I did this, the button fonts seemed to stabilize.

YMMV